# Link between quadratic Brownian motion and squared Bessel process

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I am trying to express the following one-dimensional quadratic Brownian motion process in terms of a one-dimensional squared Bessel process:
$$Z_{t}=\alpha^{2}W_{t}^{2}-2\beta W_{t}$$
with $\alpha>0$ and $\beta>0$.

I would like to know in particular what its specific scale and starting point would be.
I would expect a squared Bessel with scale $\alpha^2$ that starts from $\beta^2/\alpha^2$ but I am not sure how to get there.

Same question then but with time-dependent parameters:
$$Z_{t}=\int_0^t\alpha^{2}_{s}dW_{s}^{2}-2\int_0^t\beta_{s}dW_{s}$$
with $\alpha_{t}>0$ and $\beta_{t}>0$ and adapted (with good conditions).

---

Addendum: based on jakobdt's remarks, here is what I am thinking...

---

We have:
$$Z_{t} =\alpha^{2}W_{t}^{2}-2\beta W_{t}
 =\alpha^{2}\left(W_{t}-\frac{\beta}{\alpha^{2}}\right)^{2}-\frac{\beta^{2}}{\alpha^{2}}$$

with:
$$Z_{t}+\frac{\beta^{2}}{\alpha^{2}}\geq 0$$

and thus:
$$\left|W_{t}-\frac{\beta}{\alpha^{2}}\right|=\frac{1}{\alpha}\sqrt{Z_{t}+\frac{\beta^{2}}{\alpha^{2}}}$$

Deriving $Z_t$ in time:
$$dZ_{t} =\alpha^{2}\left[dt+2\left(W_{t}-\frac{\beta}{\alpha^{2}}\right)d\left(W_{t}-\frac{\beta}{\alpha^{2}}\right)\right]
 =\alpha^{2}\left[dt+2\left|W_{t}-\frac{\beta}
{\alpha^{2}}\right|\mathrm{sgn}\left(W_{t}-\frac{\beta}{\alpha^{2}}\right)d\left(W_{t}-\frac{\beta}{\alpha^{2}}\right)\right]$$

where:
$$\mathrm{sgn}(w)=\begin{cases}
1 & w\geq0\\
-1 & w<0
\end{cases}$$

Introducing:
$$B_{t}=\int_{0}^{t}\mathrm{sgn}\left(W_{s}-\frac{\beta}{\alpha^{2}}\right)d\left(W_{s}-\frac{\beta}{\alpha^{2}}\right)$$

we have:
$$\langle B\rangle_{t}=\int_{0}^{t}\mathrm{sgn}^{2}\left(W_{s}-\frac{\beta}{\alpha^{2}}\right)ds=t$$

whence $B_{t}$ is a Brownian motion. Therefore, we can write
$$dZ_{t} =\alpha^{2}\left[dt+2\left|W_{t}-\frac{\beta}{\alpha^{2}}\right|dB_{t}\right]
 =\alpha^{2}\left[dt+\frac{2}{\alpha}\sqrt{Z_{t}+\frac{\beta^{2}}{\alpha^{2}}}dB_{t}\right]$$

Now, if we define $Z'_{t}=Z_{t}+\frac{\beta^{2}}{\alpha^{2}}$, we can as well re-write:
$$dZ'_{t} =\alpha^{2}\left[dt+\frac{2}{\alpha}\sqrt{Z'_{t}}dB_{t}\right]$$
with $Z'_{0}=\frac{\beta^{2}}{\alpha^{2}}$. Then $Z'_{t}$ is a squared Bessel process starting from $\frac{\beta^{2}}{\alpha^{2}}$ with some $\alpha$ scaling.

Comment: Do you want $Z$ to be a squared Bessel process? Note that $Z_t<0$ with positive probability and that a squared Bessel process cannot be negative.

Comment: I expect $Z_t$ to be a squared Bessel process plus a shift, I presume. Since $Z_t$ starts from 0, I guess the underlying squared Bessel process would start from minus the shift, something like that.

Comment: Presumably, by completing the square, one gets $$Z_{t}=\alpha^{2}\left(W_{t}-\frac{\beta}{\alpha^{2}}\right)^{2}-\frac{\beta^{2}}{\alpha^{2}}$$... But how to move from here to a standard squared Bessel process is still my question.

Comment: Would it perhaps be easier to write down an expression for $\mathrm{d}Z_t$? Although, the process $\left(W_t-\frac{\beta}{\alpha^2}\right)^2$ looks like the squared Bessel process that you are looking for?

Comment: Hello jakobdt. I wrote an addendum to my question. What do you think?

Comment: It looks all good to me. However, my understanding of a squared Bessel process starting from some $x>$ is that it is defined to be a process with the law of $(B_t)^2$, where $B_t$ is a Brownian motion starting at $\sqrt{x}$. So you simply need to rewrite $\alpha^2(W_t-\beta/\alpha^2)^2=(B_t)^2$, where $B=-\alpha W+\beta/\alpha$. Theorem 5 in [this blog](https://almostsuremath.com/2010/07/28/bessel-processes/) provides two equivalent definitions, one of which is the SDE definition.